# Connect two Guest OS's in VMWare WorkStation 10.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, vmware-workstation

I have installed `Ubuntu 12.04` in `VMWare WorkStation 10.0` and I want to connect and `ping` / `ssh` the another `Ubuntu 12.04` which is installed in the same host OS in `VMWare WorkStation 10.0`

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

How did you set your network interfaces on both nodes?

If you don't know much on networking, set both network adapters to "bridge", so you can get ip addresses from DHCP from yourlocal router, and in the same range...that way you can ping, SSH or whatever as if you had phisical machines...

Comment: Is it possible when using NAT

Comment: Should be possible, haven't tried it, but if you translate your local address, shouldn't be difficult...will try to simulate it..

Answer (score 0):

it depends on yours Network Adapter Setting. if you set Bridge: then it will gain directly access from your Physical Network. and if you set NAT: used to share Host ip address. or if you set Host only: A private network share with the Host Network.

Comment: Maybe consider making it a list (using a dash and indention) to make it more readable. :)